# How to create a curvey layout in android

Tags: java, android, android-tabs

I need  a suggestion to implement the following bar as seen in the picture below. I am lost in which layout manager should i use

My desginer has given me the bar background and all the buttons seperately . I know that I have to use framelayout to put the buttons on top of the bar , but I am lost as to how to position those buttons precisely in the curve.

Any hits ?[image]

Comment: In case you are successful at doing this, please do share the strategy or sample code and put it as an answer. This might help the others who will come on the question later. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways can be the following:

For getting the curve, leave the upper frame layout as it is. Concentrate of the tabs. For the individual tabs you can precisely create the drawables in a way that a portion(curvy) of there background is transparent. You might have to be precise is while making that small curvy portion as transparent. That's my 2 cents for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit like above, you can simply create the background to be a curved image inside of a normal linear layout, and place the drawables for the buttons accordingly.